# How to check if two columns are consistent in a table. sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling to ask the question so I will just put an example table. Basically, if I have two columns with headings `person` and `insured car`, how can I check if the same person consistently insures the same brand of car.

```
 ------|------
|person|brand |
 ------|------
|  0   |Toyota|
|  0   |Mazda |
|  1   |Toyota|
|  1   |Toyota|
|  2   |Honda |
|  2   |Honda |
|  3   |Ford  |
 ------|------
```

So basically in this table I want to filter out person 0 because he insures both Toyota's and Mazda's, however the other people exclusively insure one brand of a car.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the people and car, you can use aggregation:

```
select person, min(brand) as the_brand
from t
group by person
having min(brand) = max(brand);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. would you also be able to help me with how to filter out the consistent ones (i.e only keep person 0 and filter out the rest)?

Comment: @Michael . . . You could use `<>` rather than `=` in the `HAVING` clause.